# Many docker volumes, each for different user (swarm mode)

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have users that each will each have a directory for storing arbitrary php code. Each user can execute their code in a Docker container - this means I don't want user1 to be able to see the directory for user2.

I'm not sure how to set this up.

I've read about bind-mounts vs named-volumes. I'm using swarm-mode so I don't know on which host a particular container will run. This means I'm not sure how to connect the container to the volume mount and subdirectory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered having an external server for storage and mounting it on each Docker host? 
If you need the data to exist and you don't want to mount external storage you can try looking into something like Gluster for syncing files across multiple hosts
As for not wanting users to share directories you can just set the rights on the folder.

Comment: Yes I'm looking into doing nfs right now. I'm going to check the gluster option too.  I'm not sure how to setup the rights/access on the folder though... does this mean I need to create users inside each container? And how to I ensure the container user and access/read/write to their folder on the host?